# onRequestPermissionsResult funciona de forma no esperada sin preguntar en un diálogo

Tags: android, android-permissions

Tengo un problema con la nueva forma de pedir permisos en Andorid (a partir de la 6.0)
intento pedir por un diálogo al usuario que permita a la aplicación acceder a la cámara a través del método `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` pero en lugar de saltar el diálogo entra directamente al override de `onRequestPermissionsResult`.
Primero defino el permiso en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Después, en mi main activity defino un valor para el callback del permiso:

```
 private final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA=1;
```

Posteriormente llamo a la comprobación desde mi `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        abrirCamara = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            abrirCamara.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        }
    }
```

Este es mi override del `onRequestPermissionsResult`:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode,
            String permissions[],
            int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    abrirCamara.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

El resultado esperado de todo esto es que al iniciar la aplicación pregunte al usuario si quiere permitir el acceso a la cámara de la misma, pero en su lugar, me entra siempre como si ya tuviese los permisos necesarios sin preguntar, es decir, no salta el diálogo y según he comprobado haciendo debug entra en el `case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA:` del método `onRequestPermissionsResult`.
Estoy utilizando la versión de SDK más reciente.

¿qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba añadiendo mal los permisos en el Manifest.xml, lo tenía tal que así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mi.paquete.camaraandroid">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Desconocía que los permisos no pueden ir dentro de la etiqueta application, para declararlos correctamente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mi.paquete.camaraandroid">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Permisos deben definirse dentro del tag <manifest pero no dentro de <application developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining.html

Answer (score 1):

Si definiste los permisos y si se entra al método `onRequestPermissionsResult()` sin requerir permisos y no envía el mensaje, quiere decir que ya están asignados los permisos, puedes verificarlo en la configuración, ve a aplicaciones y revisa en los permisos de la aplicación, si esta activado no mostrará el dialogo.

Puedes desactivarlo e iniciar tu aplicación entonces se mostraría el diálogo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En cuanto a los permisos, estos deben ser definidos dentro del tag `<manifest` y afuera de `<application`

mas información : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining.html

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, el error venía del fichero Manifest, hago una respuesta para explicarlo.

Comment: Ups! si, los permisos deben estar dentro del tag <manifest pero no adentro de <application https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining.html

Answer (score 0):

Si estás debugueando en un dispositivo virtual, la aplicación corre con el usuario root y se le otorgan todos los permisos sin interacción con el usuario. Si estás usando un dispositivo físico para correr la aplicación asegúrate que la API target sea la 23 o superior.